# Data fusion pipeline- wrangler transformation not working

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

Datafusion pipeline
Source  is a csv file in GCS
Wrangler -- > Tried to validate few columns like below

Mobile_Number(column) -- > send to error --> value matches regex expression - >^[0]?[789]\d{9}$

When the similar transformations are added, wrangler is failing with errors. 
And also how to check the records that were filtered during validation. I can't even find which 
validation has failed.

Comment: Adding the transformations                                                                                                    send-to-error MOBILE_PHONE =~ "^[0]?[789]\d{9}$"
send-to-error MOBILE_PHONE =~ "(\d)\1{9}"
send-to-error FULL_NAME =~ "^[a-zA-Z]+$"

Comment: Could you share a screenshot with the error, and an example of the CSV file?